# Copy Workflow From One Server to Another

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, customization

I have created workflows in test server(CRM 2011) & now I want to copy some of my workflows to prod server(CRM 2011).

How to Copy workflow(s) across the servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy workflows in the same way you deploy other CRM components: Using [solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx).

In your solution go to *Processes* -> *Add Existing* and choose your existing workflows. Afterwards you can export the solution and import it in the production environment.